A task won't trigger after a BranchPythonOperator calls it
I'm trying to achieve max performance in the case I'm working on. 
I'm parsing jsons and when the first three tasks:

check_cm_files_present_task
check_cmts_struct_files_present_task
check_cmts_meas_files_present_task

detect any new file in either one of three GCS locations it should trigger one of the file moving tasks:
-
check_cm_files_present_task

move_to_valid_cmts_struct
move_to_valid_cmts_meas

and in parallel it should also trigger dataproc cluster creation task (to save time)
So far I am unable to achieve it. 
Whataever task id I set in the return message or set trigger rules or rearrange dependencies the task: "create_cluster_task" won't start.
Here is a piece of code I'm using:
def check_cm_files_present():
regex = re.compile(r"(.*?).gz")
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=PREFIX)
jsons = [blob for blob in blobs if regex.match(blob.name)]

if len(jsons) > 0:
    return ["move_to_valid_cm","create_cluster_task"]
else:
    return ["exit_task"]




with models.DAG(dag_id='job-json-to-csv',
    schedule_interval="0,15,30,45 * * * *",
    description='',
    default_args=default_dag_args,
    max_active_runs=1) as dag:

check_cm_files_present_task = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='check_cm_files_present_task',
    python_callable=check_cm_files_present,
)

check_cmts_struct_files_present_task = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='check_cmts_struct_files_present_task',
    python_callable=check_cmts_struct_files_present,
)

check_cmts_meas_files_present_task = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='check_cmts_meas_files_present_task',
    python_callable=check_cmts_meas_files_present,
)

exit_task = DummyOperator(
    task_id='exit_task',
    trigger_rule='one_success'
)

create_cluster_task = DummyOperator(
    task_id='create_cluster_task',
    trigger_rule='one_success'
)

check_cm_files_present_task >> move_to_valid_cm >> other_task1
check_cm_files_present_task >> create_cluster_task
check_cm_files_present_task >> exit_task
check_cmts_struct_files_present_task >> move_to_valid_cmts_struct >> other_task2
check_cmts_struct_files_present_task >> create_cluster_task
check_cmts_struct_files_present_task >> exit_task
check_cmts_meas_files_present_task >> move_to_valid_cmts_meas >> other_task3
check_cmts_meas_files_present_task >> create_cluster_task
check_cmts_meas_files_present_task >> exit_task
create_cluster_task >> create_dataproc_cluster

And here is the log from the check_cm_files_present_task. It should follow the ["move_to_valid_cm", "create_cluster_task"] but it never does. It always gets skipped.


Do you have any idea why is that happening?

in your BranchPythonOperator callable shouldn't you be just returning the name of one task instead of a list i.e.
return "move_to_valid_cm"

you can specify the order of tasks in the bottom of the DAG
previous_tasks >> [move_to_valid_cm, exit_task]
move_to_valid_cm >> create_cluster_task


That maybe true but the create_cluster_task never gets triggered, even if I specify the return value to return "create_cluster_task" and the order of tasks to move_to_valid_cm >> create_cluster_task. This is super annoying and I'm running out of ideas why this might be happening. It's almost like the trigger rule doesn't work for this particular task
